# RabbitMQ new connection refused due to SocketException

Tags: java, connection, rabbitmq, amqp

while trying to create a new connection to rabbitmq running on a different server, I got the following error:

```
java.io.IOException
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:406)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:516)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:533)


Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset


at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)



Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:131)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:533)
```

---

> Steps taken :

- rabbitmq is running on the server.
- server is specified
- default port is specified

> lsof -i tcp:5672

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

beam.smp 3084 rabbitmq   15u  IPv6  18611      0t0  TCP *:amqp (LISTEN)

> rabbitmqctl list_connections

Listing connections ...
guest   client_server   55765   running
...done.

> netstat -tapnl | grep 5672

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3084/beam.smp

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55672               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3084/beam.smp

tcp        0      0 :::5672                     :::*                        LISTEN      3084/beam.smp

Comment: Which RabbitMQ version?

Comment: rabbitmq version  : 3.0.4 and the server is running on a centos machine.

Comment: 1. Does it work in local host? could be a firewall problem.
2. Try to execute `rabbitmqctl list_connections` on the server, you could have too many open connections.

Comment: Yes it works in localhost . I tried a simple producer-consumer program. I also executed the rabbitmqctl list_connections command and got only two ports in the list and rabbitmqctl list-queues command listed only two queues currently .I restarted rabbitmq server and tried afresh , to no result .

Firewall is not a problem .I have verified . Any other bottle-necks I might be missing ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think it's a tcp socket problem! Did you try **telnet your_server 5672**  from the client ?

Comment: yea i think that is the problem ! 

telnet your_server 5672  gives the following result : 

Trying your_server...
Connected to your_server.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Answer (score 23):

One of the possible reasons is that user you are connecting with to RabbitMQ has no rights to access to virtual hosts.

You can check this using Management Plugin (Admin tab).

Answer (score 6):

- Do not specify the default port as you have mentioned in your steps.
- If you have not created virtual host on the actual server, where you are trying to connect, Do create a virtual host and give it admin permision.
- Set the virtual host on the factory before creating the new connection, like factory.setVirtualHost("VIRTUAL_HOST_NAME_ON_SERVER");
- Make sure username on the server on which you are trying to connect is Admin and have access to the Virtual Host you just created.
- Specify your username and password along with virtual host, while getting the connection.
- Start your application in Debug Mode, and check if it now passes, factory.newConection();

This should make your things work.
Got the same exception, and it worked for me.

If it still does not work paste your code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Check the host and port value

In application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

[image]

See RabbitMQ site is running on port 15672 whereas in code using amqp protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the SSL/TLS support is enabled. Then use the instruction useSslProtocol :

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.useSslProtocol();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scene, I create a rabbitmq-server on hostA, then start a client on hostB and try to connect the rabbitmq on hostA.
I got `Unable to connect to AMQP server` error when create a new connection. It is due to the firewall. I solved it by execute command `systemctl stop firewalld`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).